# How to access a website protected by AWS Cognito using curl

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, authentication, curl, amazon-cognito

I am trying to access a website (in this case grafana api) using curl but it is protected by cognito. We have an application load balancer with a listener rule that requires Cognito Authentication before forwarding the request to the website. When I try to open the website in a browser, I am getting redirected to the hosted UI of AWS Cognito and after logging in, I am redirected to my Website.

Thanks to Stack Overflow I managed to get an AccessToken and Idtoken however when I try to call my URL using this, I am still redirect to the Hosted UI

Instead of getting the website, I only receive the hosted UI. I also tried cognitocurl but this doesn't seem to work for my use case either. My App Client in the User Pool has the Authentication Flow ALLOW_USER_PASSWORD_AUTH and ALLOW_REFRESH_TOKEN_AUTH enabled.

```
reqData = {
    "AuthParameters": {
        "USERNAME": username,
        "PASSWORD": password,
        "SECRET_HASH": secret_hash
    },
    "AuthFlow": "USER_PASSWORD_AUTH",
    "ClientId": client_id
}

headers = {
    "X-Amz-Target": 'AWSCognitoIdentityProviderService.InitiateAuth',
    "Content-Type": 'application/x-amz-json-1.1'
}

jsonResponse = requests.post(
    url=cognito_url, data=json.dumps(reqData), headers=headers).json()

request_headers = {"Authorization": jsonResponse['AuthenticationResult']["IdToken"]}
r=requests.get('https://my_website', headers=request_headers)
print(r.text)
```